# How to automatically create local home directories for LDAP authenticated users if the home directory does not already exist?

Tags: raspbian, home, ldap

I have configured a raspberry pi 4 running raspian to authenticate users using LDAP. The LDAP server is hosted elsewhere. I am able to log in to the system as an LDAP user, but the user has no home directory. To attempt to fix this, after some searching and reading, I attempted to use `pam_mkhomedir`. To do this I added the following line to the file `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
session    required   pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

However, when I log in as the test LDAP user (the same one as before, so this is not a first time login, in case that is important), there is still no home directory. Therefore my question is, how can I have a user home directory created automatically on Raspbian for LDAP users.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/257312/336076) I think I was putting the line in the wrong file, it should have gone in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`. Once I added it to the bottom of this file, my home directory was automatically created on login.